# Given mapping of integers to characters find all possible character combinations of a given integer

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a library which contains mappings from integers to characters. I also have a string which is in the format of an integer. I am trying to write a method that will return all possible character combinations when interpreting the string. For example:
Given the following library `a=1, b=2, c=3, k=11` and the string `"1123"` the output should be a list that contains `"aabc", "kbc"` Assume all given numbers can be found in the library.

My current solutions is as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<String> d(String s) {
    ArrayList<String> s2 = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (s.length() == 1) {
        s2.add(""+library.get(Integer.valueOf(s)));
        return s2;
    }
    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        String curr = s.substring(0, i + 1);
        if (library.containsKey(Integer.valueOf(curr))){
            ArrayList<String> strings = d(s.substring(i + 1));
            char c2 = library.get(Integer.valueOf(curr));
            for (String tmp : strings){
                s2.add(c2 + tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    return s2;
}
```

Is there a more optimal way to solve this problem? Also what would be the complexity of my solution? My assumption is O(N^3) time.

Comment: It's definitely not O(N^3), considering the output size can be exponential in the length of the input.

Comment: You should specify some limitations. You didn't specify any. How big the integers from the library are, how long the input string could be, etc., etc.?

Comment: I found this question on glassdoor, there weren't any limitations provided. http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Given-a-library-of-numbers-to-corresponding-letters-1-a-2-b-3-c-etc-and-a-string-made-up-of-digits-return-how-QTN_613215.htm

Comment: That question only requires you to return the *number* of possible translations, not a list of all of them. That makes things much easier.

Comment: @user2357112 If it's just the number, things are a bit easier. But the question OP asked is about returning the list.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem maps to the following grammar:

```
S -> SA | SB | SC | SK | ε
A -> 1
B -> 2
C -> 3
K -> 11
```

This is a context-free grammar, which means any decent parser ([CYK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CYK_algorithm), [Earley](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earley_parser)) will parse it in O(n<sup>3</sup>) time as a worst case scenario. Anything worse than that and you're definitely on the wrong track.

(Note: though the grammar is context-free, the language it defines is in fact regular. The added complexity comes from the requirement that we produce all possible parse trees. If the requirement was simply to decide whether an integer is a valid sentence in our language, the regular expression `((1)|(2)|(3)|(11))+` would be enough)

Comment: Any decent parser will parse it in O(n^3) time if it only has to return one parse tree. Returning all possible parse trees can take much, much longer.

Answer (score 1):

This problem reminds me one allegedly asked to someone in a Google interview:

> Write a program to calculate all different ways to build a N height lego tower having pieces of length and width 1 and height given by a collection (i.e [1,2,3,4])

In our case `library` is the collection and we have to consider an additional constraint: A piece has to match the text.

From this, we can attempt a dynamic programming solution to calculate the number of possible "buildings":

```
public static int nCases(String s)
{
    int ncases[] = new int[s.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        ncases[i] = 0;
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Character> piece: library.entrySet())
        {
            String mapStr = piece.getKey().toString();
            int j = i+1-mapStr.length();
            int prev = 1;
            if(j-1>=0) prev = ncases[j-1];
            if(j>= 0 && s.substring(j, i+1).equals(mapStr))
                ncases[i] += prev;
        }
    }
    if(ncases.length>0)
        return ncases[ncases.length-1];
    return 0;
}
```

This solution is easily modifiable to keep track of each case and thus provide a list as you ask:

```
private static class Pair<T,L>
{

    public Pair(T first, L second) {
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    }

    T first;
    L second;
}

public static  List<String> dynamicd(String s)
{
    Pair<Integer,List<String>> ncases[] = new Pair[s.length()];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        ncases[i] = new Pair<Integer, List<String>>(0, new ArrayList<String>());
        for(Map.Entry<Integer,Character> piece: library.entrySet())
        {
            String mapStr = piece.getKey().toString();
            int j = i+1-mapStr.length();
            Pair<Integer, List<String>> prev = 
                new Pair<Integer, List<String>>(1,new ArrayList<String>());
            prev.second.add("");
            if(j-1>=0) prev = ncases[j-1];
            if(j>= 0 && s.substring(j, i+1).equals(mapStr))
            {
                ncases[i].first += prev.first;
                for(String pcase: prev.second)
                    ncases[i].second.add(pcase+piece.getValue());
            }
        }
    }
    if(ncases.length>0)
        return ncases[ncases.length-1].second;
    return new ArrayList<>();
}
```

If `N = s.length()` and `M = library.size()`, this approach has a worst time complexity of `O(N*M)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code (Which is self explanatory)

```
public static Collection<String> allPermutations(int num) {
    TreeNode root = createTree(toArray(num));
    Collection<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    allLeafNodes(root, result);
    return result;
}

private static Integer[] toArray(int num) {
    ArrayDeque<Integer> array = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();
    do{
        array.push(num % 10);
        num /= 10;
    } while  (num > 0);
    return array.toArray(new Integer[0]);
}

private static TreeNode createTree(Integer[] integers) {
    return doCreateTree(0, "", integers);
}

private static TreeNode doCreateTree(int index, String parentString, Integer[] integers) {
    String nodeData = parentString + AlphabetMatcher.match(index);
    TreeNode root = new TreeNode(nodeData);
    if (integers.length != 0) {

        root.left = doCreateTree(integers[0], nodeData, Arrays.copyOfRange(integers, 1, integers.length));

        if (integers.length > 1) {
            int newIndex = integers[0]* 10 + integers[1];
            root.right = doCreateTree(newIndex, nodeData, Arrays.copyOfRange(integers, 2, integers.length));
        }
    }

    return root;
}

private static void allLeafNodes(TreeNode root, Collection<String> result) {
    if (root != null) {
        if (root.right == null && root.left ==null) {
            result.add(root.data);
        }
        allLeafNodes(root.left, result);
        allLeafNodes(root.right, result);
    }

}

private static class TreeNode {
    private String data;
    private TreeNode left;
    private TreeNode right;

    public TreeNode(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

private static class AlphabetMatcher {
    private static final String[] alphabet = {"", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e",
            "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r",
            "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "v", "z"};
    public static String match(int number) {            
        return alphabet[number];
    }
}
```

Here is the test case

```
@Test
public void allPermutationsTest() {
    Collection<String> result = StringUtil.allPermutations(1221);
    org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(result).hasSize(5).containsAll(Arrays.asList("abba","abu", "ava", "lba", "lu"));

    result = StringUtil.allPermutations(10);
    org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat(result).hasSize(2).containsAll(Arrays.asList("a","j"));
}
```